# Case insensitivity option in complete.ly

Tags: properties, case-sensitive, complete.ly

It would be great to be able pass a `caseSensitive` option on the function call. By default it could be set to true (the current setup), but you could pass `{caseSensitive: false}` as the option param and it will return results in a case insensitive way.

I think this is something many users would find useful?

My use case is:

> I have a list of properties that are in upper and lower case. I want the hint list itself to remain this way and if a user begins typing 'uhi', 'Uhi' or 'UHI', it would show hint results containing 'Uhi Property'.

I don't necessarily want it to alter the hint list to lowercase and is a bit messy for users to create code in the `onChange` event. Would be great if this was a standard option. :)

The Draw a Robot example on the complete.ly site (see: http://complete-ly.appspot.com/examples/draw.a.robot.html ) is the closest example here as it converts input & hint text to lower case but doesn't cover the above really as options list isn't lower case to begin with (`Uhi Property`) plus we don't especially want to convert the hint list to lower case either.

Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

using match will do the job:

```
var string1 = "aBc";
var match = string1.match(/AbC/i);

if(match) {
}
```

where the 'i' stands for case insensitive

Comment: to use variables in match u can use the constructor of Regexp:

var re = new RegExp(variable, 'g');
xxx.match(re);